# How many attacks when fighting with two weapons?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

I'm making Samurai NPCs for a future campaign and I'm not sure to perfectly understand what are bonuses and penalties for a Samurai fighting with two weapons at the same time (that can be common for Dragon or Mantis samurais).

I noticed:

- The attack roll penalty, that depend of the size of the weapon for the off-hand.
- The armor TN bonus, equal to insight rank.

But nowhere in the rule book I saw if it was possible or not to **make two attacks in one action** (one with each weapon) in that situation. So is it possible or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

The fact that you are wielding two weapons just increases your armor TN, but to get extra attacks, be it main or off-hand attacks, you need the **Extra Attack maneuver** or the **rank 3 bushi school ability**, which is a different ability for each school.

Its covered in their two-weapon abilities. Though, they should have explained it better on the page 141 topic regarding two-weapon fighting and multiple attacks.

**Mirumoto Bushi**

> The Mirumoto Bushi School focuses on the mechanical benefits of
>   wielding two weapons simultaneously, both in forgiving the penalties
>   associated with doing so and improving the benefi ts. It also
>   increases the samurai’s Armor TN and **grants him additional attacks at**
>   **an increased rate** due to the availability of his weapons.

Meaning that their rank 3 ability is granted because of this two-weapon training, otherwise they wouldnt get an extra attack. Well, all bushi schools get it, but the lore explanation is because of their two-weapon training.

**Rank 1: Way of the Dragon**

> When wielding a katana in your main hand and a wakizashi in your off
>   hand, **you suffer no penalties** of any kind for dual wielding, and you
>   gain a bonus of your School Rank to your Armor TN (This is cumulative
>   with the normal bonus for wielding two weapons). Additionally, when
>   you are targeted with a spell, you may raise or lower the TN of that
>   spell's Spellcasting Roll by 5.

So they take absolutely no penalties when dual-wielding, but nowhere says they can make two attacks in one action, meaning they can't do that without raising the attack roll 5 times, which is highly unlikely to happen at rank 1, as the amount of raises you can make are limited by your Void Ring.
If they could, by rank 3 when they would be able to attack as a simple action, they would attack four times in a round.

**However**, take a look at the **Spinning Blades Kata** (pg 260 core), which the mirumoto bushi have access, it allows you to make the Extra Attack maneuver with only **3 raises** instead of 5, but that attack must be with your secondary weapon and you cannot raise for increased damage.

Comment: Even if I may didn't explain it correctly, my question was "does fighting with two weapons **directly grants** a second attack", so I have my answer: it's a no. I was supposing it, but I wanted a confirmation. So thanks you !

Comment: My apologies, i thought it was clear but i will clarify it even further.
The fact that you are wielding two weapons just increases your armor TN, but to get extra attacks, be it main or off-hand attacks, you need the Extra Attack maneuver or the rank 3 bushi school ability.

Comment: Both of which are just grant extra attacks. I'm pretty sure the only thing that explicitly grants you an attack with the off-hand weapon is the Mirumoto Bush Rank 5.